# Display notification when database has new row, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to send a notification to a user when a database table has a new row. But I have two problem.

### UPDATED

First problem is with the script below. I can send notification only if I run this route's url. `Route::get('/car/create', 'CarController@carNews');` Not when I update my DB table... How can I change this to send notification not by run the url, but by update the DB table... (also trying not to send the whole table, just new added rows.)

**Controller**

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

public function carNews()
{
    $cars = \DB::table('cars')->get();

    $user = User::first();

    $user->notify(new CarNews($cars));

    dd($user->notifications);
}
```

The second problem is about displaying the notification in blade. I can't reach inside of the data column in notifications table in DB.

```php
@foreach(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications as $notification)
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
            {{$notification->data->cars[0]['price']}}
     </a>
@endforeach
```

this giving me below error.

> Trying to get property of non-object

By the way when I try to reach the data like this. `{{$notification->data}}` I am having this error.

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

[image]

The column look like this: My path is wrong?

PS: if you need to see any other files, comment below.

Comment: May be you are looking for [broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting)

Comment: actually, i want to a send web notification to user, about new data... The database table updating automatically so when it's updated, send that to the user. with but I have problem inside the controller. I am doing it very very wrong... @NikleshRaut with my controller code, user sending notification to other user...

Comment: Event listener?

Comment: Do you want asynchronous notifications to the user? Then i would try something like http://www.pusher.com which integrates with Laravel.

Comment: I know but, pusher is the second step. First I need to display the data properly in view... @ege

Comment: is the user intended to receive the notification is the same user that inserted the row on the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer for question 1;**

if i understand correctly, you wants send a message when inserted a new row into the table. Actually, I didn't understand that you tells about which database table but never mind, I think, you can send a new notification in the action where is inserts new row to table. So, you can send notification at the moment that inserted new row.

**Answer for question 2;**
No! The paths not wrong, it is an only Json encoded data.
You must be decode it via `json_decode` after then, you can access to all object properties.

```
@foreach(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications as $notification)
  @php($data = json_decode($notification->data));
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
    {{$data->cars->price}}
  </a>
@endforeach
```

Can you try the my above advices?

Comment: thank you for the  answer. I tried your code and it giving this error. `json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` By the I didn't understand the first answer :) could you explain a bit more. Thank you

Comment: Can you show me output if the ``$notification->data`` ?

Comment: when I do this `{{$notification->data}}` it display this error. `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: The explain my first answer is, You can send notification in the place where is insert action.

Comment: No! :) You must be print via dd(). ``{{dd($notification->data)}}``

Comment: oh, sorry :)). you can see here: https://imgur.com/a/PLoUv7X by the way it's actually estate not cars but don't mind it

Comment: I think, i understood. You don't need json_decode, it comes already as a object, But the cars array looks  a multidimensional array. so you must use as ``$data->cars[0]['price']`` Can you try it?

Comment: I already tried it like this `{{$notification->data->cars[0]['price']}}` but it giving this error. Trying to get property of non-object  ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191214/discussion-between-fgdeveloper-and-barbie).